# Ionic 1 FCMPlugin.onNotification() is not triggering while click on the incoming push notification

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have integrated Fcm in my code but for ios it is not triggering the onNotification(). When I am trying to click on the incoming notifications it is not triggering just open the app.
Please help me with the issue.